# Postman API call to IGDB result filter

Tags: curl, postman

Im playing with steam and igdb api and postman.

I have credentials for both platforms.

I have called steam api to get my owned games, in particular, I have the `steam appid.` of every game I have purchased.

Now I want to cross data with igdb, the only way I found its to make an api call to

`https://api.igdb.com/v4/websites`

That endpoint could be filtered by url content

For example, with this body (in raw text)

`fields *; where url = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/813780/Age_of_Empires_II_Definitive_Edition";`

I got this response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 176751,
        "category": 13,
        "game": 55056,
        "trusted": true,
        "url": "https://store.steampowered.com/app/813780/Age_of_Empires_II_Definitive_Edition",
        "checksum": "f2da2e08-56d8-0dd4-138c-05b1fc820661"
    }
]
```

So, the steam appid its present in the url field, its there any way to filter the api call to "`url contains 813780`" or "`url like "%813780%`" or similar?

thanks!